# Prevent PyDev from moving specific imports

Tags: python, pydev, flask

While programming under eclipse+PyDev and using Flask framework, I noticed that the auto-organizing imports feature from IDE (invoked with *Ctrl+O*) sometimes gets in the way.

This is related to the way Flask deals with the need of splitting views code into multiple modules, or packages. Basically, if you have a `views.py` module that contains your request handlers:

```
from myapp import app

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello world"
```

and your Flask app is defined in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('MyApp')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

@app.before_request
def before_request(): pass # omitted for brevity

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(): pass # omitted for brevity
```

you need to `import views` *at the end* of the latter file for the view functions to be added to Flask's routing table. Since `views.py` imports `__init__.py` to access the `app` variable, this results in circular import. It works fine, though, and is in fact an established practice, as [suggested by documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/).

Unfortunately, PyDev knows nothing about this technique. Should we accidentally trigger organizing imports for `__init__.py` (not uncommon, given how useful this option is in general), PyDev will happily move the crucial `import views` to the top. Of course, this results in incorrect (irresolvable) circular import, and an annoying runtime error.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening - like a `#@Directive` that would tell PyDev to leave this specific import alone, a way to turn off import organizing on per-file basis, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use PyDev, but have you tried throwing off its import parser? This is dirty, but you could try something like:

```
if 1: import views
```

Since the line doesn't begin with "import", maybe PyDev will pass it over?

Comment: This workaround does work in PyDev... and I must say I find it less dirty than the reason it has to be used -- i.e.: working around circular imports :)

Comment: It is not limited to such workaround, but also many more types of "import hacks", such as `sys.path` manipulations.